# Is the previous basic search available in 5.66?

Tags: searchkit

After installing 5.66 on test, the previous basic search (Search/Find Contacts) has been replaced by the new Search Kit basic search, which is good.  However as a bug re. ACLs hasn't been fixed ([this one](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4513#note_152135)) I'd like to temporarily stay with the old search until it is fixed. AFAIK this doesn't seem possible - if you disable/uninstall the new SearchUI extension the old search doesn't function.  Is this by design - the old search is removed, or is there some way to get back the old basic search?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, replacement of search pages is entirely optional. Disabling the Search UI extension will restore the original searches (you may need to clear caches after doing so).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the previous search is available in 5.66 - the fact that I can't get it to work must be something to do with the extensions I have installed. I've just installed a new, clean version of 5.66 and the previous search works there & seems to be the default. When I figure out the full answer I will expand this.  See Coleman's reply below - I uninstalled SearchUI extensions and now I have the previous search.